# ¿Como puedo modificar la ruta en que un archivo se va a guardar?

Tags: java, android

Hola necesito ayuda para modificar la ruta destino de un archivo en una aplicación Android, mi código crea el archivo pero no es visible y necesito que por ejemplo se guarde en la carpeta Documents de la memoria interna esta carpeta posiblemente se deba crear

Este es mi codigo

```
 protected void CreaArchivo(){
    OutputStreamWriter archivo = null;
    try {
        archivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("PruebaArchivo.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
        archivo.write(et1.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(this,"Archivo Creado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(this,"No se ha podido escrbir",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    finally {
        try{
            if (archivo != null){
                archivo.close();
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Y posteriormente utilizar la nueva ruta para leer el archivo y por el momento así es mi codigo

```
 protected void LeerArchivo(){
    InputStreamReader flujo = null;
    BufferedReader lector = null;
    try{
        flujo = new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("PruebaArchivo.txt"));
        lector = new BufferedReader(flujo);
        String texto = lector.readLine();
        while (texto != null){
            tv1.setText(texto);
            texto = lector.readLine();
        }
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(this,"No se ha podido leer",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    finally
    {
        try {
            if(flujo!=null)
                flujo.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Obten la ruta del directorio /Documents y crea el archivo mediante:

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
File file = new File(dir,"PruebaArchivo.txt");
```

Este sería el cambio de acuerdo a tu código:

```
...
...
 try {

       File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
       File file = new File(dir,"PruebaArchivo.txt");

       FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //archivo = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("PruebaArchivo.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
        archivo = new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream);

        archivo.write(et1.getText().toString());
        Toast.makeText(this,"Archivo Creado",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Toast.makeText(this,"No se ha podido escrbir",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
 ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

como puedo cambiar la ruta de guardado de un archivo creado con el write

```
    File fileEntradaV = new File(txtV);
    FileOutputStream flujoSV = new FileOutputStream(fileEntradaV);
                 
    String infV= datosVD;
    byte [] resultadoVD = new byte[infV.length()];
    for (int i=0; i<infV.length();i++){
        
    
    resultadoVD [i]= (byte)infV.charAt(i);
    }
    
    flujoSV.write(resultadoVD); // <--- es este
    flujoSV.close();
```

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/361457)